# Pyramid Volumes Sum

Tags: geometry, summation, 3d

Let ABCD be a tetrahedron whose edges have length 5. Consider the set of pyramids of the form AMNP where M lies on AB, N lies on AC, and P lies on AD such that AM, AN, and AP $\in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Compute the sum of the volumes of all such pyramids.

I attempted this problem by assigning coordinates and using shoelace theorem. I ended up getting a form that I found the expected value of, but it was completely incorrect. Also, I was stumbling around with my solution, assuming things.

Essentially, I am stuck. It would be great if anyone could provide a thread to get me started.

Comment: Regular pyramid ABCD ? Don't you mean a regular tetrahedron ?

Comment: I guess it could be called a tetrahedron as well. The problem statement said pyramid, I believe they are interchangeable.

Comment: No, they are not interchangeable. Everybody on this site will prefer "tetrahedron".

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

- $|AP| = u, |AQ| = v, |AR| = w$.
- Given any 4 points $X,Y,Z,T$, let $\Delta_{XYZT}$ be the volume of tetrahedron $XYZT$.

We will use the fact under [affine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), the ratio of volumes of different shapes remain the same. If one apply an affine transform to map the vertices of original tetrahedron to new positions
$$(A, B, C, D) \mapsto (A'B'C'D') = ((0,0,0),(5,0,0),(0,5,0),(0,0,5))$$
Vertices $P,Q,R$ will get mapped to following positions

$$(P,Q,R) \mapsto (P',Q',R') = ((u,0,0),(0,v,0),(0,0,w))$$
This tells us

$$\Delta_{APQR} : \Delta_{ABCD} = \Delta_{A'P'Q'R'} : \Delta_{A'B'C'D'}
= \frac16 uvw : \frac16 5^3\\
\implies \Delta_{APQD} = \frac{\Delta_{ABCD}}{125} uvw
$$
Summing over all possible pyramids is equivalent to summing $u,v,w$ over $\{1,2,3,4\}$. This means

$$\verb/SUM/ = \frac{\Delta_{ABCD}}{125}\sum_{u=1}^4\sum_{v=1}^4\sum_{w=1}^4 uvw = \frac{\Delta_{ABCD}}{125} (1+2+3+4)^3 = 8\Delta_{ABCD}$$

If you look up the volume of a [regular tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Regular_tetrahedron) on wiki (or just compute it by hand), you will find

$$\Delta_{ABCD} = \frac{5^3}{6\sqrt{2}}\quad\implies\quad\verb/SUM/ = 8\Delta_{ABCD} = \frac{250\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! May I ask how you got from $\sum_1^4\sum_1^4\sum_1^4 uvw$ to $(1+2+3+4)^3$?

Comment: Notice $uvw$ are product of 3 independent factors in $u,v,w$. So $\sum_{w=1}^4 uvw = uv (\sum_{w=1}^4 w)$ Since the last factor doesn't depend on $u,v$, you can move it outside the sum of $u,v$. i.e. $\sum_{u=1}^4\sum_{v=1}^4\sum_{w=1}^4 uvw = \left(\sum_{u=1}^4\sum_{v=1}^4 uv\right)\left(\sum_{w=1}^4 w\right)$. Do the same thing to the other two factor will give you above factorization.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes sense. Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may know that one of the easiest way to describe a regular tetrahedron with coordinates is to select 4 vertices among the 8 vertices of a cube in this way:

$$A(0,0,0), \ B(0,a,a), \ C(a,0,a), \ D(a,a,0)$$

One can check easily that all points are at the  same distance, equal to $\sqrt{a^2+a^2}$. As this distance must be equal to 5, we must take:

$$a=5/\sqrt{2}$$

The volume of tetrahedron defined by

$$\|\vec{AM}\|=m/\sqrt{2}, \ \ \|\vec{AN}\|=n/\sqrt{2}, \ \ \|\vec{AP}\|=p/\sqrt{2}$$

with $1 \le m,n,p \le 4$ is classicaly given by:

$$V_{m,n,p}=\dfrac{1}{3!}\det \begin{pmatrix}|&|&|\\\vec{AM}&\vec{AN}&\vec{AP}\\|&|&|\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac16\det \begin{pmatrix}
0&n/\sqrt{2}&p/\sqrt{2}\\
m/\sqrt{2}&0&p/\sqrt{2}\\
m/\sqrt{2}&n/\sqrt{2}&0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{mnp}{6 \sqrt{2}}$$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Is my solution understandable ?

Comment: Yes, thanks very much! The elementary solution is preferred, but I will write this one up as well.